# MySQL - insert if doesn't exist yet

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I want to execute this MySQL query:

`` INSERT INTO `cron-stats` (`user`) VALUES (".(int)$d['by-user'].") ``

Whenever such user doesn't exist yet, as in:

```
SELECT 1
FROM `cron-stats`
WHERE `user` = ".(int)$d['by-user']."
```

How can I execute this in one query?

Comment: And add IGNORE after INSERT

Comment: Have you already studies the [`INSERT` syntax reference page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

```
INSERT INTO `cron-stats` (`user`) VALUES ('yourValue')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user = user;
```

- [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

but in order to perform the `INSERT` statement well, you need to set a `UNIQUE` index on column `user`.

if the column has no `index` yet, execute the statement below,

```
 ALTER TABLE `cron-stats` ADD CONSTRAINT tb_un UNIQUE (`user`)
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps. I'm using this in a CRON, where I'm running ``UPDATE`` for existing entries. Before the ``UPDATE`` runs, I want to prepare not existing entries by INSERTing null values. Is this the proper solution?

Comment: what's the reason why you need to insert null values first?

Comment: Oh well, it doesn't work. Here's the full query with the error: http://pastebin.com/PyHMY9RG

Comment: you have key word `SET` in the query which is not suppose to be there. remove it and execute it again.

Comment: it's not the same. Oh, i see a `WHERE` clause at the end of the query. remove it also.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23405/discussion-between-jw-and-rimmer)

Comment: Interestingly, when you use the 'duplicate_key_update' statement and it prevents an insert, it still advances the AUTO_INCREMENT for that table.

Answer (score 6):

A little bit hacky, but if you use a `SELECT` derived table instead of `VALUES` you can do:

```
INSERT INTO `cron-stats`(`user`)
SELECT u
FROM (SELECT @dByUser AS u) x
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `cron-stats` WHERE `user` = @dByUser)
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91546f/1)

Comment: Is this guaranteed to be atomic? 

That is, if two inserts come in at the same time, could they both pass the WHERE NOT EXISTS part and both insert?

Answer (score -3):

You can try this using if else condition

```
$chk = mysql_query("select 'the username' FROM `cron-stats`");
$rs = mysql_fetch_array($chk);
if($rs == "")
{
    $ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cron-stats` (`user`) VALUES ('.(int)$d['by-user'].')");
} 
else{
    echo "Duplicate entry";
}
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution since you're losing out hugely on performance benefits and ACID.  You'd really need to wrap this in a transaction to make it work right, and why would you do that anyway when there are clear commands that are so much better?