# Insert multiple records in table if IDs do not exist in table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to add multiple records in a single table for multiple employees if the employees ID's do not already exist in the table. I have the employee IDs in array.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [EmployeeID] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [EmployeeID] => 2 ) )
```

Now I have a table where I want to check that if record exist for employees then don't insert if record for certain employee don't exist then do the insertion.

e-g I have table.

```
INSERT INTO timesheet (employee_id,date_created) Values (1,2014-12-20),(2,2014-12-20) where employee_id NOT IN (1,2)
```

I know the above query I wrote is not right but that's why I want to ask how to insert in to table only if the records do not exist for that certain ID.

I'm using `codeigniter`, if you also know in `codeigniter` way that would be great. But simple `mysql` query help can also work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [NOT EXIST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) clause like this:

```
INSERT INTO timesheet (employee_id,date_created) 
select 1,'2014-12-20'
from dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM timesheet 
   WHERE employee_id in (1)
);
```

*For multiple rows, you have to add dummy rows as following (or just execute previous statement in loop)*

```
INSERT INTO timesheet (employee_id,date_created) 
select * from (
    select 1 AS ID,'2014-12-20'
    union all 
    select 2 AS ID, '2014-12-20'
    union all 
    select 3 AS ID, '2014-12-20'
) t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM timesheet 
   WHERE employee_id = t.ID
);
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3ea6/1)

Thanks to [Spock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4352356/spock) for correction! :)

Comment: can we directly use not exist without using the subquery??
I mean WHERE NOT EXIST(1,2) etc??

Comment: I don't think so, since you want to compare existing rows from table. Directly specifying `where not exist(1,2)` according to your expectation--think with which column it should match?

Comment: yeah @Spock, I'm afraid he needs to run multiple queries. Let me update answer!

Comment: sorry, but that one is not going to work either... here's a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/805f45/6) I'll update my answer with the problem in your version

Comment: Thankyou for replies. But there are alot of queries that are going to execute. and if i have many employees the number of queries will be too many.. :(

Comment: Any way to insert record with minimum queries to execute.?

Comment: @SizzlingCode Then just use it in loop!

Comment: Then you would need to write PHP code to get existing employee ids from database and remove those employee_id from array (you wanted to insert), and then proceed insertion. No other way AFAIK!

Comment: @SizzlingCode. Yes, but only *if `employee_id` is primary key* on `timesheet` table. Is it ? (I think it will not be primary key for timesheet table).

Comment: no its not primary key but it is foreign key..
I guess i will have to follow the php way. i mean select employee ids not in table then do the insertion to be save from alot of queries.

Answer (score 1):

Start by making sure employee_id is a primary key and/or uniquely indexed.  Then, you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

See this as a reference: [MySQL - insert if doesn't exist yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534972/mysql-insert-if-doesnt-exist-yet)

Answer (score 1):

```
$data=Array ( Array ( 'EmployeeID' => 1 ),Array ( 'EmployeeID' => 2 ) );
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($data);
 foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo $str="INSERT INTO timesheet (employee_id,date_created) Values (1,2014-12-20),(2,2014-12-20) where employee_id NOT IN ($key)";
    echo '<br>';
 }
```

[image]